# Fibonacci Sequence (conceptual/mechanical)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, fibonacci-numbers, divergent-series

I'm in Calc II and have my exam on series/sequences tomorrow. There will be an extra credit question related to Fibonacci and am trying to gather as much info on the sequence as possible.

-If the Fibonacci sequence is increasing, and the ratio between any two consecutive numbers for an=(an-2) + (an-1) (for large values of an) wouldn't it be bounded and thus convergent (monotonic)?

-is there anything I need to know about the reciprocals? To my knowledge an accurate sum of the reciprocals hasn't been found.

Thanks for any info/links you have on the topic

Sorry if this is not an appropriate question. I just found this forum today and thought I'd ask a couple questions pertaining to subject material.

Comment: There is no link between your questions and Fibonacci numbers. Please take the time to write down a question that's understandable. What is $a_n$. What series is increasing? What ratio?

Comment: $F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}\right)^n - \left(\frac{-\sqrt{5}+1}{2}\right)^n\right)$ @oasiscakes

Comment: See [OEIS A$079586$](http://oeis.org/A079586).